# How to call Rest webService from android with using android adt eclipse?

Tags: android, web-services, rest

How to call a webservice from android ? I am new to android,any one can send some link,how to do or any tutorial how to start from the scratch.

I want to use restwebservice for an android adt eclipse,and tell me how to use with the existing website ?

**After clicking the button,it has to show that website,how to use http for that one?but in http its showing only the string**

Comment: Here is a great link "http://androidexample.com/Restful_Webservice_Call_And_Get_And_Parse_JSON_Data-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=101&aaid=123"

Answer (score 3):

Firstly add following to your manifest. This is to request for a permission to access the internet.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Then the simplest way to hit a webservice is use the [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) bundled with android:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URL));
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
    out.close();
    String responseString = out.toString();
    //Whatever you wanna do with the response
} else{
    //Close the connection.
    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
}
```

Comment: where we want to give our url,and where we want to put this code,can you tell me some full details,i am new to android,can you tell me how to do fully

Comment: there is something called `URL` in the second line. You give your `URL` there and this is the whole code to hit a **webservice**. You need to put it wherever you want to call it.

Comment: can you tell one thing,is any lib function is needed.if in that url place i want to put http:\\www.ibettertechnologies.com,is it possible,and one more thing if i click an button it has to open that company addres,how to do it

Comment: no need to add any external jars for this. And for basic android functionality, you need to check the [cookbook](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html).

Comment: it shows error,my url is "http://www.google.com" is it correct

Comment: after adding the url it shows lots of errors

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0srHQ1nk        see this link,my application has stopped coming,inlog cat

Comment: ,can you please tell me how to solve the error

Comment: it says:- `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. try to use an [`AsyncTask`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example) for all your network related calls.

Comment: can you please tell me,how to do this in my code,i want if i click the send button ,that website has to dispay

Comment: @RJ,how to do that one,see my code in pastebin and tell

Comment: How to use the Asynctask and where i have to use that one,i dont need the string,i want that webpage

Comment: i think your code will comes string only